# No record found for selection of Trigger with key<> when quartz tried to fetch job details after restart of application

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Getting exception when quartz tried to fetch data regarding stored job details.

> Exception - nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: No record found for selection of Trigger with key:? and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and truncated all the quartz tables and restarted the app and that sorted the issue for me.

Here is the script I run on postgres

```
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_job_details CASCADE;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_triggers CASCADE;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_fired_triggers;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_locks;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_paused_trigger_grps;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_scheduler_state;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_simple_triggers;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_simprop_triggers;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_blob_triggers;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_calendars;
TRUNCATE TABLE quartz.qrtz_cron_triggers;
```